# How to build a p2sh who's scriptsig contains a Signature

Tags: bitcoin-cash, p2sh, scrypt, input-script

I have created a P2SH address, funded it, and am attempting to move the funds with a TX.

The redeemScript for the TX requires the TX signature (OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY), but in order to create this signature, the TX preImage must be created and hashed.  However, the preImage for a P2SH contains the TX redeemScript itself...this seems to create a loop wherein this functionality is not possible.

Am I doing something incorrectly, or am I overthinking things?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to review BIP16 (pay to script hash)
https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki

The signature is not included in the redeem script, typically just the public key. (Your script could be anything, all I know is it has a `CHECKSIGVERIFY` in it, so I'm answering broadly...)

The INPUT SCRIPT aka `scriptSig` of the transaction SPENDING from the P2SH output would then need to contain the signature and the entire serialized redeem script (the preimage to the script hash in the output).

Comment: After more reading, it looks like the redeemScript is the serialized script of the spending TX...and after dumping some variables, looks like my underlying issue is an incomplete preImage.